# Discord.py delete message from user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to create a bot that delete message from a user with a mute command but i don't know how to do it. My code here.

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):    
#Get the member's id
    global user_id
    user_id = member.id
#Send a messaage saying the user is muted
    await ctx.send(f'{member} muted')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    global user_id
    if msg.author.id == user_id:
        await msg.delete()
```

I don't know how to let the event use the variable that created in the command.

When I use the command mute someone
the bot just automatically delete the message sent by that someone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So the command will delete the last 1 message from the user? In the same channel where the command is used or across all channels?

Comment: Do you have to use the muting that deletes every message? Or does the new *time out* feature of discord work for you?

Answer (score 0):

find the solution

```
user_id = 2

@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    global user_id
    user_id = member.id
    await ctx.send(f'{member} muted')

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.author.id == user_id:
        await msg.delete()
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).